# Optimal way of working with a regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to isolate just the name of a group.

Doing this command:

```
Get-ADUser aaa00 -Properties memberof |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof
```

returns:

```
CN=GroupName,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx
```

I want only what is after `CN=`, which is the group name.

So I'm doing:

```
Get-ADUser aaa00 -Properties memberof |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $isolateName = $_ -match "(?<=\=)(.*?)(?=\,)"
        $matches[0]
    }
```

which works and returns only the group name.

However, I want to store the group names in an array for later use, so I'm doing:

```
Get-ADUser aaa00 -Properties memberof |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $isolateName = $_ -match "(?<=\=)(.*?)(?=\,)"
        [array]$Names += $matches[0]
    }
```

This works fine.

My question is, is that the optimal way to work with RegEx?

I do the `-match` then check `$matches` but couldn't I just do it inverted and do "replace all that is NOT what is matched by my regex by nothing".

How do I do that, basically negate that whole Regex?

P.S.: I know I can use `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` to get the name only but I'm not using that command since it is incredibly slow compared to `Get-ADUser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, which uses the `-replace` operator to extract the group names:

```
$groupNames = Get-AdUser gar25 -properties memberof | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^CN=(.+?),.*', '$1' }
```

<sup>Note: Assumes that group names contain no *escaped* `,` chars. (`\,`).</sup>

- The array of group names is implicitly created simply by assigning the entire pipeline to variable `$groupNames`. (If there's a chance that only *1* group may be returned and you want to make sure that the result is an *array*, enclose the entire pipeline in `@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator.
- `$_ -replace '^CN=(.+?),.*', '$1'` extracts the group name from each input:

  - `^CN=` matches literal `CN=` at the start (`^`) of the input string.
  - `(.+?)` non-greedily (`?`) matches a nonempty run of arbitrary characters (`.+`), and uses a capture group (`(...)`) to capture that run.
  - `,.*` matches a literal `,` followed by a (greedily matched) potentially empty run of arbitrary characters (`.*`), i.e., it matches the remaining input.
  - Since the capture group matches non-greedily, it captures everything up to the *first* `,` char, which is assumed to be the group name.
  - Overall, the regex by design matches the entire input string, so that by only using `$1`- what the 1st capture group captured - as the replacement operand it is just the group name that is returned.